# Unable to set image in image view

Tags: swift

I'm getting an error saying "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in the below bolded line of code. I'm using Xcode 7.2

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    **myImageView.image = image**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set image before dismissing view controller.

```
myImageView.image = image
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a question mark to avoid the problem:

```
myImageView?.image = image
```

Comment: The image is not displayed in view. It is empty. Error goes of, but in console a message as follows is coming: _Snapshotting a view that has not been rendered results in an empty snapshot. Ensure your view has been rendered at least once before snapshotting or snapshot after screen updates._ Do i need to do anything?